# Newsletter subscribtion confirmation email are going in spam

Tags: newsletter, magento1.9.2.4, confirmation

All transaction mails are working fine except newsletter confirmation link.

I already checked the markup and talked to my hosting provider which told me that the email header looks good. I think the link is the problem but without the confirmation link the email is of course useless.

Looking for help to fix this.

Comment: is it all newsletter subscribers or just certain domains? Have you tried yourself?

Comment: Mostly Gmail and Yahoo recipients. Yes, i tested it with various mail-accounts by myself. Some went through and others not.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the mail with a HTTPS url of you website, perhaps it will be considered as more secure

Answer (score 0):

You must be facing this issue because of the settings of your domain and its reputation. It has nothing to do with Magento.

Please have a look:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en-uk&hlrm=en

Check if there are any other problems, which might lead to low domain reputation.

However, to know more about how spam filters work and what are the effective steps to tackle this issue, follow this guide:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-avoid-spam-emails-magento/

Comment: Spf-Record is already set. But I'll try some of the other suggestions.